# Can someone help why my zcat command is not working?

Tags: unix

```
zcat ../{$var} | tar xvf -
```

here var = file name that I want to extract but it is showing below error can someone help

```
No such file or directory 
command not found
```

Comment: `{$var}`? Sure about that?

Comment: try `zcat ../${var} | xargs tar xvf - `